# react-native bridge ios 10 push notifications, bridge to notification service extension

Tags: ios, react-native

I am thinking about writing a module to use all the new ios 10 notification features in react-native.

One issue I have is that the new notifications use the Notification Service/Content Extensions, which are separate binaries/targets.

Does this mean that is impossible to bridge the react javascript code to them?